# Вопрос по cookies

Tags: php, cookie

Подскажите, первый раз использую куки.

Не могу понять, почему отображает кнопки после ответа. Что исправить?

Исходник
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B07aYSnGHQe9SzRhOE03YXE4NW8&usp=sharing

А так выглядит
http://s-v-a.in.ua/DNR-VS-ATO/t.php

Comment: [GrammarNazi mode on]

    Вы проголососвали за: Единую Украины<br />За Новороссию - 39<br />
    <br />За Единую украину - 29<br />
    <form method="POST">
    <input type='submit' name="nov" value="Новоросия" >
    <input type='submit' name="ukr" value="Обьеденная Украина" >

За "Обьеденную" Украину украинцы не проголосуют, равно как и оппоненты за "Новоросию".

[GrammarNazi mode off]

А по существу, никто из дежурных телепатов не в курсе, что же такого там секретного содержится в "php/golos/golos.php".

Comment: а че не в курсе? Я же открыл файл 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B07aYSnGHQe9aTlkUGJXZXl2LXc&usp=sharing&tid=0B07aYSnGHQe9SzRhOE03YXE4NW8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправить — начать сесии: `session_start()`.

Вообще посмотрите еще раз в общем [про механизм сессий с примерами](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php).